# How to manage multiple projects in the same repository?

Tags: git, github

**Background**: I'm working on a Formula Student Team (we develop and build a race car each year) and until now we did not have any kind of version control. From now on, we will use GitHub to manage our projects. The projects are in constant evolution, so even though the car is running with some version of the PCBs and software, they both keep evolving.

**Setup**: We have one repository for all the different projects (dashboard, data aquisition, BMS, safety circuits & logic PCBs...). As of now, we stored the current version of each project that makes the car work, along with some common libraries and documentation.

### **Question**: How can we define the concept of release? In other words, how to manage all the projects knowing that they do not evolve at the same rate?

Keep in mind that everything is constantly under development, so maybe a new version of the BMS comes in March and a new version of the dashboard comes in September, but the competitions are in July-August, so the car we compete with might have or not the projects developed that year.

The solution that came to my mind was the following:
Use a release branch for each project. Making it a protected branch, and merging them to the main branch prior to the competitions to have a record of which version of every project was in the car for the competitions, with a "safe version" for each one.

I don't feel like that is a good idea because I had never used version control for something this big before, and I want to make the best possible decision in this aspect for the team, as the repository is meant to be something atemporal and a bad decision could cause a lot of harm in the coming years.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why not use a repository per distinct component? You could use branches, but then you'll have long-living branches for each component, which only contains a certain component in a usable state, and the others in an unknown state. Then how will you merge the developments done on the various components? How will you pull updates on other components into a release?

Comment: The intent is to unify coding style and format in the following years (reviews by everybody should be mandatory), and to standarize the use of common libraries. Using multiple repos would make that a bit complicated and in the long run, each component would have its own particularities which may not be debuggable by someone who did not develop said project. I do not know very well how merging works exactly, but I guess you can select which specific directories you would like to merge.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, that's not how merging with Git works. Each branch is a representation of the entire repository at a certain moment in time (i.e. a certain commit).

Comment: "Release" and "branch" are orthogonal, or mostly so. The usual way to define "release" is entirely administrative. While version control is a good idea, it's not part of the definition of a release.

Comment: As to the subject line question (which is a bit different): Git stores a *graph* of commits, and while this G=(V,E) graph set is required to be a DAG, it *can* be *disjoint*. So you can store multiple independent graphs within one repository. There's little point to doing that though: it gains you no advantage over using separate repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be solved using git's `submodule` feature.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

create a new empty repository

```
mkdir reslease_repo
git init  reslease_repo
```

change into this new repo and checkout the other repos each in a separate subdier to  `reslease_repo`

```
cd reslease_repo
git clone [url-of-first-module] first-module
git clone [url-of-second-module] second-module
# ...
```

Go into each submodule and checkout the commit that should be part of the delivery

```
cd first-module
git checkout [branch|tag|commit-id]
```

Then go back to reslease_repo and add the modules directory

```
cd ..
git submodule add [url-of-first-module] first-module
```

Repeat that for all modules.

The content of the modules will **not** be checked in into the `reslease_repo`.

When cloning `reslease_repo` add the git parameter `--recurse-submodules` to fetch their content along with the main repo.